# Performing a Redox Titration on a Vitamin C Sample Solution Containing Cellulase enzymes

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration, titration

I was wanting to performing an Iodometric Redox Titration on a Vitamin C sample solution created from allowing diced citrus fruits to sit in a water + cellulase solution. Because vitamin c is water soluble, the water +enzyme solution should possess a fair Ascorbic acid concentration, to which I planned a redox titration for its analysis.

> This method determines the vitamin C concentration in a solution by a redox titration using iodine. Vitamin C, more properly called ascorbic acid, is an essential antioxidant needed by the human body (see additional notes). As the iodine is added during the titration, the ascorbic acid is oxidised to dehydroascorbic acid, while the iodine is reduced to iodide ions.
> $$\ce{ascorbic acid + I2 -> 2I− + dehydroascorbic acid}$$
> Due to this reaction, the iodine formed is immediately reduced to iodide as long as there is any ascorbic acid present. Once all the ascorbic acid has been oxidised, the excess iodine is free to react with the starch indicator, forming the blue-black starch-iodine complex. This is the endpoint of the titration.

Explanation taken from https://www.canterbury.ac.nz/media/documents/science-outreach/vitaminc_iodine.pdf.

I was wondering it the water + cellulase solution I’d be titrating on was viable for this way of determining Vitamin C. Will cellulase interfere with the reaction which governs this titration?

Comment: Why you want to add a cellulase solution to the reaction mixture?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne To catalyze the hydrolysis of the cellulose cell wall of the citrus fruit placed inside the water solution, and see how that effects Ascorbic acid release

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't think cellulase affects iodination titration, but think it may hydrolyze starch indicator so that end point might not be visual.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Cellulase only catalyzes the breakdown of cellulose, but starch is made up of amylose and amylopectin polysaccharide chains. In this case, cellulase wouldn’t interact with the starch indicator, correct? However, if this were the case, should I use a higher concentration starch indicator solution?

Comment: I've searched for that. But it wasn't clear whether cellulase catalyzes the breakdown of only $\beta$-D-linkages or not because some literature uses starch linkages as substrate. Easy way to find this is run a sample titration with known ascorbic acid concentration (you need to scandalize your iodine solution anyway). Use extra sample with and without cellulase and compare the results.